# Are query parameters in Angular state URLs carried to nested states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `angular^1.8.0` and I have several substates that I would like to all have access to a common URL parameter. I don't have any route at `/`.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('app', {
        url: '?hl',  // also tried /?hl
        resolve: {
          handleHl: function($stateParams) {
            console.log($stateParams); // outputs { hl: undefined ... } for all routes
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard'
      });
```

Is there any way to make this work? Or do I have to edit the `url` parameter of all the substates?

Comment: Are you using ui-router? Have you tried `url : ':hl'`

Answer (score 0):

You defined a query param, and you want to see it in state params.

According to the ui-router [doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing):

The state params should be start with `:`

```
:hl
```

The query params can be specified following a '?'

```
?hl
```

Comment: An important point to note, using a state param on the root state would cause all sub-state routes to require it. Using OP's root and dashboard example, urls would have to follow the form `/{h1}/dashboard` in order to access the dashboard state. As would any other sub-state such as `/{h1}/details`. Which is fine as long as something like `account` was its own state, but that means any common modules `account` depends on can't use `app` as a root state to resolve those from and must be resolved twice from a single bootstrap. Probably not an issue, but an important implementation detail.

Comment: As @MarkClark suggested, I need this to be an optional query parameter, not a required parameter in the path. And I am seeing it as a key inside the `$stateParems` object- it's just undefined.